# Why or when are threads deleted by community

Tags: support

It's not clear why [this](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/23372#tab-top) thread was deleted - no explanation was given: I was trying to edit the question to ask if: when some manifest coercion is itself sufficient reason to reasonably assume the individual will explicitly consent, then that isn't consent, whether or there is consent.

I was considering posting the same question but worded better, but now I'm not sure - cos no explanation was given...

Comment: That thread was deleted by actions from community members (not mods) -- meaning several people thought it was a poor question and voted to close and delete it.